# Shorter and more efficient way of writing this Java code

Tags: java

What is the best way to write this code and avoid repeatedly?

```java
if (doAction() || checkNumber() || canMove() || avoidAttackersWhileHeal()) {
    return;
}

if (doCast() || doAttack()) {
    return;
}
```

I have a ton of methods like this, and each method that returns true means it won't continue, but coding style like this is ugly. Is there any other way to write it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about code optimization and should be asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: In addition to Jens's comment: When you're going to Code Review, please make sure to read their help page. A question with this limited information isn't suitable there. So please read the help page and adapt your question.

Comment: i would rater tend to "it is broad"(, but still keep open) , but maybe also wrong place at codereview..

Comment: Terrible title. Re-write to summarize your particular technical issue.

Comment: I cannot see any repetitions or efficiency hazards. If all of this `[ton] of methods` does not change state, you can call in order of increasing ratio *expected runtime/termination probability*.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can wrap your single methods in separate `Predicate` and then build a common predicate with required operations. This final `Predicate` hides all `if...else`.

```
private final Predicate<Void> predicate;

{
    Predicate<Void> doAction = in -> doAction();
    Predicate<Void> checkNumber = in -> checkNumber();
    Predicate<Void> canMove = in -> canMove();
    Predicate<Void> avoidAttackersWhileHeal = in -> avoidAttackersWhileHeal();
    Predicate<Void> doCast = in -> doCast();
    Predicate<Void> doAttack = in -> doAttack();
    predicate = doAction.or(checkNumber).or(canMove).or(avoidAttackersWhileHeal).or(doCast).or(doAttack);
}

public void doIt() {
    predicate.test(null);
}
```